# How do I install javahl _without_ pulling in all the openjdk stuff?

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, dependencies, svn

On my linux box (oneiric, 64bit) I'm running Eclipse and java straight from the Eclipse/Oracle tarballs. I'd like to install the javaHL subversion libraries, which according to the [subclipse wiki](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL) are packaged in the `libsvn-java` package, but if I do an

```
apt-get install libjava-svn
```

apt-get will pull down all sorts of dependencies related to openjdk, which I don't really care for. I'm not that familiar with apt-get too. Is there a way around this? Can I just install the shared libraries, without all the other stuff?

Answer (score 1):

download the lib-svn source package and build manually, in that case it wont download all dependecies by itself and you can avoid openjdk stuff.

Check this [article](http://en.newinstance.it/2009/05/13/making-eclipse-javahl-working-recompiling-subversion-from-the-sources/) on how to compile svn from sources

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://blog.ethomasjoseph.com/2010/07/solving-eclipse-errors-with-svn-1-6.html) I can just [download the deb package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libsvn-java) and extract the files in the right location. In my case that's just

```
cp $WHERE_I_EXTRACTED_THE_DEB/CONTENT/usr/lib/jni/* $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64
```

and no need to tell java where to look for libraries.